# The best gerber viewer or methodology for spotting differences

Tags: pcb, gerber

I am working on improving my company's PCB revision process. There will be occasions where the copper layer stays the same but only the silkscreen layer is revised, and I would like to find a way to check whether there were any inadvertent changes made to the copper layer. I have tried most of the free Gerber viewer software at this point. My favorite one so far (DFM Now!) shows the Gerber differences in XOR, so if I compare two different Gerber files with the identical cooper layers the software shows nothing.

I was curious if there are any other alternatives to this Gerber viewer or better methodology of comparing Gerber files without using a Gerber viewer.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: `gerbv` can also do XOR, is otherwise rather rudimentary; it's part of the gEDA suite.

Comment: If all you want to know is if a layer has changed or not, you could probably just diff the files. Gerber files are nothing but plain text so they are easily diff-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as user_1818839, I'd say what you do sounds reasonable.

`gerbv` can also do XOR, is otherwise rather rudimentary; it's part of the gEDA suite.

KiCAD's `gerbview` also has a "differential" mode, but I've never played with it.